# Firebase RemoteConfig on server

Tags: node.js, firebase, rest, firebase-remote-config

I have a node.js web application that renders HTML server-side.

How can I access a value for a user from Firebase Remote Config server-side, so that I can enable or disable features?

Client-side this would be [getValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.remoteconfig.RemoteConfig#getvalue).

I assumed I could use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest) for this, but the documented endpoints only seem to show overall config template rather than what is returned by getValue client side.

I can see the client SDK seems to be sending a POST to

`https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectid>/namespaces/firebase:fetch`

...but as far as I can see this is an undocumented API.

Answer (score 0):

RemoteConfig works like:

1. Developers, like us, create/update our RC template in the console or by API call, defining what RC should return in each different condition, like user language or country.
2. Our customers make a fetch call to RC server with their project number and their specific signals, like their language or country.
3. Then the RC backend will evaluate the customer's signals against the RC template then decide what it will return

Based on this, we can just simply make the REST call to RC and it will repond data in proto. Then we can extract the parameter we are interested in by name. Then convert the raw string data into its specific type.